# How do I sum the values of a column based on another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe -

```
id   count   category   class
1      1       A        X 
1      10      B        X
1      2       B        X
2      3       A        Y
3      5       A        Z
3      6       A        Z
```

I want to sum all the occurences of 'value' based on the 'category' that it belongs to, for each ID. And then get all the categories as separate columns. I also want to leave the fourth column as is. So, I want to get something like this-

```
id    A   B    class
1     1   12   X 
2     3   0    Y
3     11  0    Z
```

I've tried messing around with trying to get dummy variables and using `groupby` but I can't figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='category', values='count', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)`. This is a dupe.

Comment: `df.groupby(['id','category'])['count'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)`

Comment: I'd recommend reading this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

Comment: modified the question slightly-- not sure if this still warrants a different answer. I'm pretty lost, sorry!

Comment: Nah, it doesn't. All you need is `df.groupby('id').class.first()` and concatenate this column with the result from either Wen's answer or mine.